# Login Failure while send message using WhatsApp api c#

Tags: c#, api, sms, send, whatsapp

when i'm trying to send a message using c# api to whatsApp # , it handle the OnLoginFailed event

and show me a message of loginFailed

here's my code

```
     wa.OnConnectSuccess += () =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Connected to whatsapp...");

            wa.OnLoginSuccess += (phoneNumber, data) =>
            {
                wa.SendMessage(to, mes);
                MessageBox.Show("Message Sent...");
            };

            wa.OnLoginFailed += (data) =>
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Login Failed : {0}", data);
            };

            wa.Login();
        };

        wa.OnConnectFailed += (ex) =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Connection Failed...");
        };

        wa.Connect();
```

Comment: Whats the error message it returns?

Comment: it return "not-authorized" message @YuvalItzchakov

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?